# Displaying specific array values using substr

Tags: php, arrays, substring

I want to display Yes if one of the type values begins with the letter p, however I keep outputting NONO. Any help greatly appreciated...`

```
<?php

$pals[] = array('name' => 'jon' , 'type' => 'peach');
$pals[] = array('name' => 'gore' , 'type' => 'choc');

foreach($pals as $key => $value) {
   if (substr($value['type'], 0) === "p") {
       echo "Yes";
    } else {
        echo "NO";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the manual on `substr()`, leaving the 3rd parameter out.

Answer (score 2):

Update this line :

`if (substr($value['type'], 0,1) === "p") {`

Answer (score 1):

Try substr($value['type'],0, 1)

Answer (score 0):

To make it without substr, if you want

```
<?php
    $pals[] = array('name' => 'jon' , 'type' => 'peach');
    $pals[] = array('name' => 'gore' , 'type' => 'choc');
    foreach($pals as $key => $value) {
        $type = trim($value["type"]);
        if ($type[0] === "p") {
           echo "$type : Yes\n";
        } else {
            echo "$type : NO";
        }
    }
?>
```

live demo :  https://eval.in/754179